# centering the figures in pdf documents

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I used the following to insert pdf file in latex document:

```
\documentclass[standard]{letter}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\imgi{}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\stackinset{l}{ .1in}{b}{.2in}{}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .2in}{t}{.3in}{\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{Raman1.pdf}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.5in}{c}{.4in}{}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .8in}{b}{.6in}{}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .1in}{c}{.0in}{\imgi}{%
\includegraphics[width=6.7in]{Raman2.pdf}%
}}}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but the problem is always I get a figure with shifting to right (((see the attached picture))) when I tried to increase the size of this figure I got more shifting. how can I increase the size of this figure with keeping in center?? another thing how can I get rid of the number (circulated) from my document[image: centering the figures in pdf documents]

Comment: I run your code (without your images,  with another "things") and I have no your problem ... maybe left space is from your image ...

Comment: Actually I wanted to increase the size of this figure to put it in a table but the result was small figure thats why I want to change the dimensions

Comment: Oh, well, sometimes I make a nothing fancy trick: "capture the total image that I want, then I add it with a single `\includegraphic` command"

Answer (score 2):

If I modify your example so it can be run using general images

```
\documentclass[standard]{letter}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\imgi{}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\stackinset{l}{ .1in}{b}{.2in}{}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .2in}{t}{.3in}{\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{example-image-a}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.5in}{c}{.4in}{}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .8in}{b}{.6in}{}{%
\stackinset{r}{ .1in}{c}{.0in}{\imgi}{%
\includegraphics[width=6.7in]{example-image-b}%
}}}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Then it produces two warnings

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [standard].
```

because of the spurious `standard` option  and then

```
Overfull \hbox (139.20877pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--15
```

because the specified with of 6.7in is wider than the page.
LaTeX does not centre overfull boxes, they always stick out on the right.

It also shows that the image is included multiple times

```
<example-image-a.png, id=1, 401.5pt x 301.125pt> <use example-image-a.png>
<use example-image-a.png> <example-image-b.png, id=2, 401.5pt x 301.125pt>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-a.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-a.png>
<use example-image-a.png> <use example-image-a.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-a.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-b.png>
<use example-image-b.png> <use example-image-a.png>
```

It seems that you just want to make one image `\textwidth` wide and overprint the other:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
\rlap{\hspace{-4in}\raisebox{.5in}{%
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}}}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```